# My discord bot is running twice and i can't find the problem (Python)

Tags: discord.py

I've been working on my first Discord bot as a personal project.
However, I've encountered an issue where the bot seems to be running twice :P
I've spent the past week researching, reading through documentation, and even resetting my bot token, but the issue persists.
I saw some similar questions here but none of the answers helped me
I reached out to my university teacher for assistance too, but unfortunately, he doesn't use Discord.py (as I expected tho).
Can you guys help me please?

Everytime I use a command such as `!join` the bot answers

```
Hey hey, I'm coming!
Hey hey, I'm coming!
```

When he's supposed to just say `Hey hey, I'm coming!` once.

Here's my main file:

```
import discord
import os
import sys
from discord.ext import commands

sys.path.append('./.py')
from apikeys import *
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)

  @client.event
  async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, name = 'Pewdiepie'))
  print('===================')
  print('The bot is on-line')
  print('===================')


for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
  if filename.endswith('.py'):
    print(filename)
      await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

My apikeys are stored at `../discord_bot/.py/apikeys.py` and my main file is at `../discord_bot/main.py` .

My cog files are working as they should.

Also, apologies for any grammatical errors, english isn't my native language eheh

Comment: The string `'Hey hey, I'm coming!'` doesn't appear anywhere in this code. Perhaps you're running some other program. If you want to easily debug your running bot, just add `print` statements at strategic places and watch what it outputs on the console. You might be responding to some other event and assuming it's one thing without checking what the actual event is.